# build_native.py command gives error Cocos2d-x

Tags: android, python, cocos2d-x

I have created new project in Cocos2d-x 3. When I run build_native.py that gives me following error

```
The Selected NDK toolchain version was 4.8 !
make.exe: *** F:\My: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\My Projects\cocos2d\TestGame\proj.android\build_native.py", line 159,
in <module>
build(opts.ndk_build_param,opts.android_platform,opts.build_mode)
File "F:\My Projects\cocos2d\TestGame\proj.android\build_native.py", line 146,
in build
do_build(cocos_root, ndk_root, app_android_root,ndk_build_param,sdk_root,android_platform,build_mode)
File "F:\My Projects\cocos2d\TestGame\proj.android\build_native.py", line 82, in do_build raise Exception("Build dynamic library for project [ " + app_android_root + " ] fails!")
Exception: Build dynamic library for project [ F:\My Projects\cocos2d\TestGame\proj.android ] fails!
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with your project import. Import your whole `TestGame` project, not just `pro.android`.